# I'm resigning as a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

As a moderator, I have to help this community thrive and also to represent it towards Stack Exchange.

I am convinced that many of SE's recent choices: ads, CoC changes, license changes, are actively hurting this community, which I represent.
Furthermore, many of our requests, if not almost all of them, no matter how well-received, no matter how sorely needed to make our community better, have been ignored for years.

At this point, it has become clear that Stack Exchange has no real interest in cooperating with me and you, the community that I represent.

It is, therefore, with regret that I have asked Stack Exchange to remove my diamond, to make it clear that I am not on board with the current direction set by them.

Comment: It feels quite strange to upvote something which is sad and also something that I can comprehend all too well in most of the points raised and the consequence drawn out of it. So be assured that my +1 is not for seeing you resign as such, but taking this stance and in agreement with the motivation. Thanks for having let that diamond shine for so long!

Comment: I know I said thanks elsewhere, thought I'd wish you well here too.   Its a shame to see the site lose early/founding members.

Comment: I'm sorry to see you step down; thanks for all you've done for Skeptics.SE as a moderator! I hope that you'll still be around in the community, asking and answering interesting questions.

Comment: I guess they won't let you go. 7 days later, still got that diamond.

Comment: @fredsbend someone finally did the needy

Answer (score 27):

I don't want to write a eulogy for a friend I hope to still see around the traps, but I do want to thank you for:

- setting the stage here for a successful community,
- training me up as a moderator,
- for giving me so many opportunities to think "Wait a moment. I disagree with Sklivvz. History has shown the  odds of me being right in such a situation is remote. Time to
  reexamine my evidence and logic for flaws,"
- for fighting for the site when you became an employee, and
- for posting so much high quality content here that has reached almost 3 million
  views.

I am sorry to see you go. I hope we can maintain your legacy.

Answer (score 20):

Wow! I thought your stance on keeping your diamond was more involving cold dead hands, than willing surrender. Your history here is apparent; your name is everywhere. If we were a city there would be a Sklivvz Ave.

A vigilant mod, fair, always acting in good faith, a foundational voice, you've served Skeptics since the beginning. Though we've personally bumped heads a few times, I'm saying thank you for your work and contributions. I really mean it.

Comment: Sklivvz Ave, is that Latin? :)

Comment: @Sklivvz Lol. Yeah, I mean *Avenue*, which is French. We'd have streets and stuff named after you. I think you knew that, though.

Comment: @fredsbend I sure did. I was just being facetious.