# How many users are barred from nomination here due to consequences of The Fall-19 (MonicaGate)?

Tags: discussion, election

We saw the fallout of [The_Fall-19](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337977), also known initially as Monicagate, mainly on MetaSE.

But this is also: the very reason why we *need* an election now, as two [moderators resigned](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4448) from SkepticsSE in response to that (at least partially).

During the heated debates and struggles that were prompted by the unpopular actions of StackExchange, suspension were handed out left and right on MetaSE.

Sure, nerves of the mods on MetaSE were certainly not in the distanced and relaxed mode. And in my opinion they were also quite often not accurately thinking and acting.

While I tried to keep track of every suspension issued, and adding a mental plus1 as a badge of honour to the vast majority of very respected users falling victim to this arbitrary looking regime, my system for identifying users 'brave enough to speak up in the face of injustice' was certainly not as perfect as the hidden-from-view-of-ordinary-users database that SE keeps as a 'permanent record' of 'misdeeds past' on all users. Note that I do not imply that all suspensions dealt out on MetaSE in that period were incorrect, false, in error, or unjust. Just that there were such cases, and frankly, for my tastes, their number was high. A little too high.

The thing here is:
I noticed that in my view, quite many of those who did voice their thoughts and fought for them in a civil way by means of discussion were silenced away to crowd-control the situation. Quite a few of them showed enormous virtue — and don't worry, I know a few names of quie hirep users acaross the network affected by this, but won't spell them out here – would be *exactly* of the kind of quality I'd like to see in a moderator. A mod here on this site.

Turns out, a strange decision that makes the theory of https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/ obsolete and untrue, but also in effect into an extreme and unusual form of punishment:

Disenfranchisement of good people despite having time served and the ban then rightfully and in due process lifted again:
[Let's disallow moderator nominations from people who've been suspended in the past year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-moderator-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-pa)

And perhaps even disenfranchisement of good people on and for this site despite having time served and the ban then rightfully and in due process lifted again on totally different sites, and if on MetaSE for way too often totally intransparent 'reasons' — which if I tried to watch, analyse re-trace and understand, simply could not accept as 'right'.

The overlap of two terrible decisions influencing this election seems quite obvious to me.

For a real life comparison to StackExchange, one might also look at [how democracies handled that kind of thing, for even higher 'forms of office'](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/59938/who-had-the-shortest-time-in-going-from-imprisonment-to-head-of-state-within-dem)

**Therefore, I want to know: how many potential candidates from or for this site are now bannned or at least automgically discouraged from running for mod here by that one 'let's extend punishment across all sites' decision on MetaSE?**

This is not only about The_Fall-19 on MetaSE, but 'across the network' suspensions. Although it is my firm request to get numbers that differentiate between SkepticsSE itself, other sites, MetaSE, and MetaSE during the purges of The_Fall-19.

Comment: Why?  ..........

Comment: @fredsbend Since you seem to have answered the prompting-this-Q-now-bountied-at-MetaSE as linked, and witnessed most of the ugly details from the front lines of The_Fall: I do not understand this comment. Lots of users got a slap, your account there is unlinked, many I'd perhaps liked to vote for if they'd run here don't show up on the relevant page, and the relevant page looks quite peculiar in general now. The '2 decisions' are a mistake. So I want to see some numbers I guess would be quite relevant to this 'event'; at least for me understanding things in this world.

Comment: Well, I figure if they can't run what does you knowing help accomplish? Further, I figure if they wanted to run, they'd be complaining. So the number of people who can't run, but want too, I suspect are few if any.

Comment: As for auto magic page hides or something, that's pretty conspiratorial.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think the policy is shitty, but "because of The_Fall" doesn't seem to be useful info.

Comment: First is of course: general interest. How much fallout is there? How many  'good guys' (&gals?) *are* disenfranchised. Plus: "automagically": that may sound as you describe. But it *is* what happens if you'd enter the process with that kind of tab-keeping in effect.  I tried it out. I failed. "not you again…!" Just too curious maybe, but still. How many in that boat. That's relevant info. Even if perhaps only for some.

Comment: As a curious data point, I'm interested, but it's the dregs of MSE that gives me a bad taste in my mouth. Maybe that's not fair to you or the question.

Comment: Well, sorry bout that off-taste. These "dregs" seem to affect this thing. And I want some more transparency on this whole shebang. 'They' can of course just delete this as well. Or just answer it. Either way will be an interesting data point for me. If 'the system' does not forget, why should I? Nevermind the policy of "We don't discuss…" This is important, as I kept even showing up *here,* since I thought that SE, & MSE is one (bad) thing, to be either sorted out or not in time. But that eg SkepticsSE is at least a community with some *autonomy* (as the announcement for election alludes to).

Comment: Yeah, I may've nominated myself to run for a mod position.  It'd have been a weak sell: I wouldn't be able to commit much time.  But due to the whole Monica thing, I figured it'd probably be best not to.

Comment: This is potentially impossible to be answered by the community (not even mods) unless some users have been actively tracking users on this site who got suspended on *any* SE sites, due to *this exact reason*, and within *that period*. Only SE staff can possibly answer this accurately, which I doubt if it is on their interest.

Comment: @Nat I'm sorry to hear that. You would have my vote. That's perhaps a more interesting question and even less answerable. "How many have decided to not run because of events last fall?"

Comment: I was just on MSE, and people are *still* talking about it on *every* post that comes from the company. Aren't they tired of it yet? I've never seen a mob rage so long.